# How to make a select via secondary indexes in Tarantool?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I create a space with two indexes — primary and secondary:

```lua
box.schema.sequence.create('user_seq', { if_not_exists = true })
box.schema.space.create('user', {
    if_not_exists = true,
    format = {
        { name = 'id', type = 'unsigned'},
        { name = 'bio', type = 'string'}
    }
})
box.space.user:create_index('id', {
     sequence = 'user_seq',
     parts = {'id'}
})
box.space.user:create_index('bio', {
     parts = {'bio'},
     if_not_exists = true,
     unique = false
})
```

Insert the tuple:

```yaml
tarantool> box.space.user:insert({ box.sequence.user_seq:next(), 'other stuff'})
---
- [1, 'other stuff']
...
```

I've tried to search like this:

```lua
box.space.user:select({'other stuff'})
```

And got the error:

```lua
- error: 'Supplied key type of part 0 does not match index part type: expected unsigned'
```

How I should search via secondary indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation said:

> index.index-name is optional. If it is omitted, then the assumed index is the first (primary-key) index. Therefore, for the example above, box.space.tester:select({1}, {iterator = 'GT'}) would have returned the same two rows, via the ‘primary’ index.

Use that secondary index explicitly:

```yaml
tarantool> box.space.user.index.bio:select({'other stuff'})
---
- - [1, 'other stuff']
...
```

Read more about it [in the documentation.](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/1.10/reference/reference_lua/box_index/#box-index-select)